# What is correct way to a remove few characters at the end of string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider the following code, what is the correct way to a remove the last two `<br/>` tags from the end of string in C#? I have followed very naive method, to achieve this. Can you please suggest improvements.

```
List<string> MessageList; // populated from data source
Label lblHtmlOutput = new Label();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in MessageList)
{
    sb.Append(item + "<br/><br/>");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 11, sb.Length - 1);
```

Comment: The answers provided are definitely the way to go about this particular case. Sometimes when you just _have_ to deal with string literals and their length, _never_ hard-code their length (as you have with your `sb.Remove` call with `-11`). It's so easy to change the string literal and forget to change the length value (or miscount it) resulting in incorrect results or runtime exceptions. Instead, store the string literal in a variable (or other source) and use its `.Length` property rather than hard coding the number.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't add them in the first place.  Use something like:

```
String.Join("<br/><br/>", MessageList);
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't insert them in the first place:

```
    List<string> MessageList; // populated from data source
    Label lblHtmlOutput = new Label();
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //foreach (var item in MessageList)
    //{
    //    sb.Append(item + "<br/><br/>");
    //}
    //sb.Remove(sb.Length - 11, sb.Length - 1);
    string list = string.Join("<br/><br/>", MessageList);
```